# "hören" or "anhören" for listening to opera

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> "Wollen wir uns die Oper zusammen ***_*__**?"
>
> a) hören
>
> b) anhören

From this dictionary, [anhören](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/anhoren) is used for concerts, while [hören](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/horen) is used for singers. So, does both work here, or only "anhören"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of "uns" in the test sentence, only "anhören" is possible. Even if one might say

> "Wollen wir zusammen die Oper hören?",

only *anhören* works with this reflexive construction:

> "Wollen wir **uns** die Oper anhören?"

And as others have noted, an opera is more than just an acoustic experience, so I would rather say *ansehen* than *anhören* (unless of course one is referring to a CD or radio transmission).

Answer (score 2):

I'm no fan or expert of operas, so the term might indeed be `anhören` or `hören`, but in casual language one says:

> Wollen wir die Oper zusammen sehen?

or

> Wollen wir zusammen in die Oper gehen?

In casual language, one would only use `hören` or `anhören` if referring to mere auditive playbacks. In that case, both are possible with `anhören` being prefered due to the concrete nature of the question (in opposition to `hören` being prefered in general contexts).

Comment: Die Antwort geht komplett an der Frage vorbei und sollte maximal einen Kommentar darstellen. Inhaltlich ist sie zudem falsch - je nach dem ob mir das Schauspiel oder der Gesang wichtiger ist kann ich von einem wie vom anderen reden. Ich geh' mir auch die Stones anhören.

Comment: @userunknown Das sehe ich natürlich nicht so. Ich habe auch nicht auf die individuelle Sprechweise sondern die Standardsprechweise von Ottonormalverbraucher abgehoben.

Comment: Tja, über die Oper reden aber Opernliebhaber nun mal mehr als Kulturbanausen, und was Musikkritiker sagen ist auch relevanter, als das Gestammel der Ottonormalverbraucher, die den Mund nur zum Essen aufkriegen.

Comment: @userunknown Dem Ersten (Häufigkeit des Themas) stimme ich zu, das Zweite (Relevanz) ist subjektiv. Die Antwort deckt die verschiedene Soziolekte und Fachtermini nicht ab, das behauptet sie aber auch nicht.

Answer (score 2):

As a more general rule you can think of "hören" as "to hear" and "(sich) anhören" as "to listen to".
The only exception is for uncountable, undefined acoustic sources.

> Ich höre gerne Radio, Hörspiele...

"Anhören" wouldn't work in that case. But as soon as you are talking about one piece in particular, "anhören" is better.

> Ich höre mir das Hörspiel an.
>
> Ich höre das Hörspiel.

This isn't wrong but it sounds a bit odd to me. IN questions though either version is acceptable.

> Hast du das Hörspiel schon gehört?
>
> Hast du dir das Hörspiel schon angehört?